# Find <p> elements in HTML body and insert <span> tags

Tags: preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I have a HTML file, for example:

```
<p class="label" id="p-1'>This is my sample txt </p>
<p class="label" id="p-2'>This is my sample txt </p>
<p class="label" id="p-3'>This is my sample txt </p>
<p class="label" id="p-4'>This is my sample txt </p>
<p class="label" id="p-5'>This is my sample txt </p>
```

I want the output look like this:

```
<p class="label" id="p-1'><span class ="span-class">This is my sample txt </span></p>
<p class="label" id="p-2'><span class ="span-class">This is my sample txt </span></p>
<p class="label" id="p-3'><span class ="span-class">This is my sample txt </span></p>
<p class="label" id="p-4'><span class ="span-class">This is my sample txt </span></p>
<p class="label" id="p-5'><span class ="span-class">This is my sample txt </span></p>
```

Is this possible with preg_replace? Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: Which language are you using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In php you can achieve this with:

```
<?php

$html = <<< LOB
<p class="label" id="p-1'>This is my sample txt </p>
<p class="label" id="p-2'>This is my sample txt </p>
<p class="label" id="p-3'>This is my sample txt </p>
<p class="label" id="p-4'>This is my sample txt </p>
<p class="label" id="p-5'>This is my sample txt </p>
LOB;

echo preg_replace('%<p class="label" id="p-(.*?)\'>(.*?)</p>%sim', '<p class="label" id="p-$1\'><span class ="span-class">$2</span></p>', $html);

?>
```

**EXPLANATION:**

```
<p class="label" id="p-(.*?)'>(.*?)</p>

Options: Case insensitive; Exact spacing; Dot matches line breaks; ^$ match at line breaks; Greedy quantifiers; Regex syntax only

Match the character string “<p class="label" id="p-” literally (case insensitive) «<p class="label" id="p-»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(.*?)»
   Match any single character «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the character string “'>” literally «'>»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «(.*?)»
   Match any single character «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the character string “</p>” literally (case insensitive) «</p>»

<p class="label" id="p-$1'><span class ="span-class">$2</span></p>

Insert the character string “<p class="label" id="p-” literally «<p class="label" id="p-»
Insert the text that was last matched by capturing group number 1 «$1»
Insert the character string “'><span class ="span-class">” literally «'><span class ="span-class">»
Insert the text that was last matched by capturing group number 2 «$2»
Insert the character string “</span></p>” literally «</span></p>»
```

`DEMO:` http://ideone.com/YaZG2p

Comment: How would it be achieved by JS/JQuery?

Comment: Great! that is working in php. Can any one help me to acheive this using JS/JQuery?

Comment: For Js you can try something like: `result = subject.replace(/<p class="label" id="p-(.*?)'>(.*?)<\/p>/ig, "<p class=\"label\" id=\"p-$1'><span class =\"span-class\">$2</span></p>");`